# How to compare values with lookup table

Tags: sql, plsql

I am having one table "Mark" which contains marks of different subjects.  If marks fit into one particular range then I should pick up respective rank and insert into marks table itself in column 'rank_sub_1'. could you please help me how can I look up in the table and insert in the column. Below is my table structure.

```
**Marks**   
Subject1_Marks  Subject2_Marks
------------------------------
71              22
10              40

**LookupTable**     
Rank    range1  range2
----------------------
9         10    20
8         21    30
7         31    40
6         41    50
5         51    60
4         61    70
3         71    80
2         81    90
1         91    100
```

Now I want to check marks of each subject with lookup table which contains the ranges and ranks for different marks obtained.

```
**Marks**           
Subject1_Marks  Subject2_Marks  Rank_Sub_1  Rank_Sub_2
------------------------------------------------------
71              22      
10              40
```

If marks fit into one particular range then I should pick up respective rank and insert into marks table itself in column 'rank_sub_1'. could you please help me how can I look up in the table and insert in the column.

Comment: What if the Subject1_Marks fits in two different ranges? Your ranks in the lookup table overlap (for instance 20 belongs to both rank 9 and 8). Also, what database are you using?

Comment: I am using oracle database.

Comment: Value will won't overlap if marks > rang1 and <=range2 then it should fit. I will change my data little bit for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Considering there is no overlapping in range values)

Take two instances of lookuptable and join first with subject1_marks and second with subject2_marks. Here i haven't used LEFT JOINS as i am assuming your subject marks will fall under 1 range for sure. If you are not sure about that, please use left joins and handle null values as per your requirement for columns RANK_SUB_1 and  RANK_SUB_2

```
WITH LOOKUPTABLE_TMP AS (SELECT * FROM LOOKUPTABLE)
SELECT M.*, L1.RANK AS RANK_SUB_1, L2.RANK AS RANK_SUB_2
FROM MARKS M , LOOKUPTABLE_TMP L1, LOOKUPTABLE_TMP L2
WHERE M.SUBJECT1_MARKS BETWEEN L1.RANGE1  AND L1.RANGE2
AND M.SUBJECT2_MARKS BETWEEN L2.RANGE1  AND L2.RANGE2
```

Then MERGE the data into table MARKS.

Solution:

```
MERGE INTO MARKS MS
USING
(
SELECT M.SUBJECT1_MARKS, M.SUBJECT2_MARKS, L1.RNK AS RANK_SUB_1, L2.RNK AS RANK_SUB_2
FROM MARKS M , LOOKUPTABLE L1, LOOKUPTABLE L2
WHERE M.SUBJECT1_MARKS BETWEEN L1.RANGE1  AND L1.RANGE2
AND M.SUBJECT2_MARKS BETWEEN L2.RANGE1  AND L2.RANGE2
GROUP BY  M.SUBJECT1_MARKS, M.SUBJECT2_MARKS, L1.RNK, L2.RNK
) SUB
ON (MS.SUBJECT1_MARKS=SUB.SUBJECT1_MARKS AND MS.SUBJECT2_MARKS =SUB.SUBJECT2_MARKS)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
SET MS.RANK_SUB_1=SUB.RANK_SUB_1, MS.RANK_SUB_2=SUB.RANK_SUB_2;
```

Tested on below schema and data as per your question's details.

```
CREATE TABLE MARKS (SUBJECT1_MARKS NUMBER, SUBJECT2_MARKS NUMBER , RANK_SUB_1 NUMBER, RANK_SUB_2 NUMBER)

INSERT INTO MARKS (SUBJECT1_MARKS , SUBJECT2_MARKS ) VALUES (71, 22);

INSERT INTO MARKS (SUBJECT1_MARKS , SUBJECT2_MARKS ) VALUES (10, 40);

CREATE TABLE LOOKUPTABLE (RNK NUMBER, RANGE1 NUMBER , RANGE2 NUMBER)

INSERT INTO LOOKUPTABLE VALUES (9, 10, 20);

INSERT INTO LOOKUPTABLE VALUES (8, 21, 30);

INSERT INTO LOOKUPTABLE VALUES (7, 31, 40);

INSERT INTO LOOKUPTABLE VALUES (6, 41, 50);

INSERT INTO LOOKUPTABLE VALUES (5, 51, 60);

INSERT INTO LOOKUPTABLE VALUES (4, 61, 70);

INSERT INTO LOOKUPTABLE VALUES (3, 71, 80);

INSERT INTO LOOKUPTABLE VALUES (2, 81, 90);

INSERT INTO LOOKUPTABLE VALUES (1, 91, 100);
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this`update`statement should do what you want:

```
UPDATE Marks m
   SET Rank_Sub_1 = (SELECT l.Rank
                     FROM LookupTable l
                     WHERE m.Subject1_Marks BETWEEN l.range1 AND l.range2)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM LookupTable l
  WHERE m.Subject1_Marks BETWEEN l.range1 AND l.range2
);
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd827/1)

If you want to update the value for`Rank_Sub_2`at the same time you can do this:

```
UPDATE Marks m
   SET Rank_Sub_1 = (SELECT l.Rank
                     FROM LookupTable l
                     WHERE m.Subject1_Marks BETWEEN l.range1 AND l.range2)
      ,Rank_Sub_2 = (SELECT l.Rank
                     FROM LookupTable l
                     WHERE m.Subject2_Marks BETWEEN l.range1 AND l.range2)
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9affd8/1)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the design below which eliminates the possibility of overlaps or gaps. Although I usually use this technique with dates, any data that defines an unbroken sequence will work the same way. The idea is that you only define where the range starts. It is understood that the range stops at the last value possible less than the next higher range. However, notice I added a tenth rank, in case values less than 10 are possible. Any values greater than 100 will, of course, show as rank 1.

```
with
Lookup( Rank, Cutoff )as(
    select 1, 91 union all
    select 2, 81 union all
    select 3, 71 union all
    select 4, 61 union all
    select 5, 51 union all
    select 6, 41 union all
    select 7, 31 union all
    select 8, 21 union all
    select 9, 10 union all
    select 10, 0
),
Marks( Mark1, Mark2 )as(
    select  71, 22 union all
    select  10, 40 union all
    select  21, 101
)
select Mark1, l1.Rank as Rank1, Mark2, l2.Rank as Rank2
from    Marks   m
join    Lookup  l1
    on  l1.Cutoff =(
        select  Max( Cutoff )
        from    Lookup
        where   Cutoff <= m.Mark1 )
join    Lookup  l2
    on  l2.Cutoff =(
        select  Max( Cutoff )
        from    Lookup
        where   Cutoff <= m.Mark2 );
```

The output:

```
Mark1       Rank1       Mark2       Rank2
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
71          3           22          8
10          9           40          7
21          8           101         1
```